# Radius of Convergence of a Finite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we want to find the radius of convergence of the Taylor series expansion of $fx) = x^6 - x^4 + 2$. As we continuously take derivatives, we find $f^{(6)} x = 720$ and, finally, $f^{(n)} = 0$ for $n > 6$. Thus, this collapses to a finite sum. I am to assume, based on the instructions, that this has a power series representation--though the coefficients, though alternating, don't appear to follow a clear pattern.

As for finding the radius of convergence, since each term is of the form $c (x-a)^n$, and the terms are defined for all $x$, can we say that the radius of convergence is $\infty$? Are there circumstances for which this wouldn't be the clase? (for example, if the function was undefined at some number $x = a$)?

Thanks.

Edit: Also, to make the logic step from saying being defined from $(-\infty, \infty)$ necessitates a radius of convergence of $R = \infty$, is it sufficient to look at the original function, or should I inspect each term? This seems reasonably self-explanatory, I think, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Our $f(x)$ is a polynomial and it is given by its Maclaurin expansion. Since the domain of a polynomial is $\Bbb R$, then the radius of convergence is infinite. Formally you could apply the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. Because almost all terms of this expansion are zero, the appropriate root limit ($\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$) venishes. This means that the radius of convergnece is infinite.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is an important point that has not been addressed in the answer by @szw1710 :

What guarantee do we have that the Taylor expansion around any point $a \neq 0$ is not infinite ?

It is because every polynomial of degree $n$ can be decomposed in a unique way on $\{(x-a)^n , (x-a)^{n-1}, \cdots (x-a), 1 \}$ which constitutes a basis of the set of polynomials of degree $\leq n$. We are thus back to the comfortable case of a finite number of terms.

Remark : You ask about the case where a polynomial wouldn't be defined for a certain $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, but this cannot occur...